# Naive linear algebra in vector bundles

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles

I would like to ask a fairly general question: how much of naïve linear algebra remains true for vector bundles? For example,

1. If $F$ and $F’$ are two subbundles of $E$ such that the fiber $E_x$ is the internal direct sum $F_x$ and $F’_x$ at each point $x$, is it true that $E$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of $F$ and $F’$?
2. Is the quotient of $E\oplus F$ by $E$ isomorphic to $F$?
3. Is the direct sum $E\oplus F$ the product / coproduct in the category of vector bundles over a fixed manifold? What if the base is not fixed?

My intuition says that the answers to these questions should be yes, but intuition for linear algebra could fail for vector bundles. If they are true, could you provide a reference for the proof or at least a general idea of the proof?

Comment: Most of the properties of vector spaces extend to vector bundles as they are locally trivial. Most of the proofs for vector spaces hold very similarly replacing the word "basis" with the word "local frame". In particular, you can easily prove that any short exact sequence of vector bundles over a fixed manifold splits, and so the Whitney sum is a biproduct in this category as the direct sum is for vector spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 3. is already addressed in Federico T.'s answer. Here is one way of thinking about Questions 1. and 2. that I like. The most important fact here is, in my opinion, the

**Proposition:** If $E,F$ are vector bundles over a topological space $X$ and $f\colon E\rightarrow F$ is a bundle map, then $f$ is a bundle isomorphism if and only if it is a fiber-wise linear isomorphism.

Together with universal properties, this answers your questions. For question 1., the subbundles come with inclusion bundle maps $F\rightarrow E$ and $F^{\prime}\rightarrow E$, which induce a bundle map $F\oplus F^{\prime}\rightarrow E$. This is a bundle isomorphism iff it is a fiber-wise linear isomorphism iff, for every point $x$,  $E_x$ is the internal direct sum of $F_x$ and $F^{\prime}_x$. Question 2. can be addressed similarly.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, quite a lot! And the reason is quite simple: as the vector bundles are locally trivial, you can use a local frame to repeat most of the proofs you do in linear algebra using a basis. In particular the facts you guessed are true and the proofs are not different from the ones you would do for vector spaces. In Milnor-Stasheff "Characteristic Classes" you can find the proofs or some hints to check them.

In the category of vector bundles over a fixed space, the Whitney sum is a biproduct, and kernel/cokernel exist for all morphism of constant rank. This makes it an additive category.

If you let change the base space, things go slightly worse: if $E \to M$ and $F \to N$ are vector bundles, their Whitney sum is obtained summing their pullbacks along the projections
$$M \leftarrow M \times N \to N.$$
Therefore, their sum $E \oplus F$ is still a vector bundle, but now over $M \times N$. This still behaves as a product in this category, but it is no more a coproduct as there is no canonical way to inject the factors into their product.

A nice remark is that linear algebra can be recovered from the theory of vector bundles just observing that any vector space is a vector bundle over a point. This lets you embed it in this context in a very elegant way.

Comment: "This makes it an Abelian Catgeory." This is not true. As you note, some condition is necessary for a morphism to have a kernel/cokernel (locally constant rank is sufficient, I think it might actually be necessary, too).

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer to include this correction

Comment: I don't think it's quite accurate still. You can't really consider only morphisms of (locally) constant rank, because those do not even form a category. Also, I retract my earlier claim about necessity. The endomorphism $(t,v)\mapsto(t,tv)$ of the trivial rank $1$ bundle over $\mathbb{R}$ does not have constant rank, but it has the trivial rank $0$ bundle as categorical kernel.

Comment: @Thorgott I don't see how two morphisms of (locally) constant rank can compose in something which is not of constant rank. Can you provide an example?

Comment: You can take (everything is considered as trivial bundles over $\mathbb{R}$) $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C},\,(t,v)\mapsto(t,e^{it}v)$ (it looks like a spiral in $3$-space) and the projection $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},\,(t,x+iy)\mapsto(t,x)$. They each have constant rank $1$, yet the composite has rank $0$ at the points $(4k+1)\pi/2,\,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and rank $1$ elsewhere.